# Graphical library for Angular

Tags: library, software-development, web-development, editor, angular

I need to make graphical editor in Angular.

That editor will be able to make **uml class diagrams** and **use case models** (something as class diagrams and use case models in power designer). Does exist some Angular free library which I should use? I found something very similar, but it is not free.

Comment: [Essential Diagram](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/diagram/uml-Class-diagram) is an option but its only free through the community [license](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense). I will add as an answer if that's acceptable to you.